# BeautifulSoup object returns as NoneType

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The following code is supposed to download the logo image at pythonscraping.com but returns the error:"

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

". It seems the error lies in the fact that the BeautifulSoup bs object returns as Nonetype.

All BeautifulSoup objects that have been called with the same exact code work so far. Where is the error in this case please? Thanks.

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen('http://www.pythonscraping.com')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
imageLocation = bs.find('a', {'id': 'logo'}).find('img')['src']
urlretrieve(imageLocation, 'logo.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error in line

```
imageLocation = bs.find('a', {'id': 'logo'}).find('img')['src']
```

It happened because of the second find
Because the a tag does not find the desired id
so returns None and you cant use "find()" for 'NoneType' object

If this code has been used in the past
There may be changes to the html page that will require a new code